# PHP/MySQLI select multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, mysqli, prepared-statement

**Hello all,**

This query below contains the prepared statement that I would like to have mysqli processed

```
"SELECT password, salt FROM accounts WHERE username=?"
```

So far there seems to be no documentation on how fetch_array() works in OO-style with prepared statements. The closest thing I can find is http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Is there a particular "correct" way of doing it with mysqli prepared statements (the OO way)? thanks!

Comment: Don't store passwords in the database!

Comment: So at which the passwords are stored..??

Comment: Actually the passwords are stored as sha256 hashes, The salt is supposed to work in a *very* strange way (not the conventional salt you stick to both ends and hash again) so I don't have that implemented yet, What I really want now is being able to select multiple columns in mysqli preparedstatements, Object oriented style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get Objects directly out of the database with prepared statements.

Use `fetch` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php to loop through the results, creating the required class instances and assigning them the data.

A model class will typically have a `read` method that does this. The method returns a instance, or an array of instances.

(Have a look at symfony models: http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/08-inside-the-model-layer There are so-called *peer models* that provide static methods "to retrieve records from the tables. Their methods usually return an object or a collection of objects of the related object class".)

Comment: So that means... I can't do it like the old fashioned way with fetch_array() -.-? I thought prepared statements work a little differently xP

Comment: OK. There doesn't seem to be a `fetch_object` equivalent with prepared statements. You'll have to use fetch: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php